# Leaving a function to hide the map causes it to show a wrong location as its centre

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map and two buttons. One to show and the other to hide the map. If I remove hideMap function the map will be shown properly (Show all markers and they are at the centre of the map), 
but if I leave the hideMap function, the map still shows the markers, however it shows a wrong location as its centre with a wrong zooming.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/82q354aw/) is updated but does not work properly. Please let me know how to make it work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>    
        <div id="map1" onClick="showMap()">Show</div>
        <div id="map2" onClick="hideMap()">Hide</div>    
        <div id="mymap" style="width: 380px; height: 800px"></div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
        <script>  

        function hideMap() {
            $("#mymap").hide();         
        }

        function showMap() {
            $("#mymap").show();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        }

        var map;
        var markers = [];
        var pinColor = "FE7569";
        function pinImage(imagenum) {
            return image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                    "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="
                            + imagenum + "|" + pinColor);
        }

        function initialize() {
                    var locations = [
              [
                'Alexs loc', '37.9908372',
                '23.7383394', '0',
                'id-90'], [
                  'John Jamess loc', '37.9908372',
                  '23.7383394', '1',
                  'id-89'], [
                    'Normans loc', '38.075352',
                    '23.807885', '3',
                    'id-12'],  [
                      'Jack Moores loc', '37.9908372',
                      '23.7383394', '2',
                      'id-67'],  ];

            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'),
                    mapOptions);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();                      
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();                      
            markers = [];

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                var place = locations[i][0];
                var placeLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    title : place,
                    position : placeLoc,
                    icon : pinImage(i + 1)

                });

                markers.push(marker);
                bounds.extend(marker.position);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
                        (function(marker, i) {
                            return function() {
                                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, i));
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
            var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
                map.setZoom(10);
                google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
            });
            hideMap();
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have time to dig into this, but don't use the same `id` twice. That'll cause issues and may be related to the problem you're having.

Comment: @Scheda which id are you referring to? I am going to add a demo to the question shortly.

Comment: id='map' is what I'm referring to

Comment: @Scheda I see no that does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the center of the map once it has a size.  Call .show, trigger resize, then center the map (otherwise it centers in a zero size map in the upper left hand corner of your div...)

```
function showMap() {
  $("#mymap").show();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2mzrwLyt/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function hideMap() {
  $("#mymap").hide();
}

function showMap() {
  $("#mymap").show();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

var map;
var markers = [];
var pinColor = "FE7569";
var bounds;

function pinImage(imagenum) {
  return image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=" + imagenum + "|" + pinColor);
}

function initialize() {
  var locations = [
    [
      'Alexs loc', '37.9908372',
      '23.7383394', '0',
      'id-90'
    ],
    [
      'John Jamess loc', '37.9908372',
      '23.7383394', '1',
      'id-89'
    ],
    [
      'Normans loc', '38.075352',
      '23.807885', '3',
      'id-12'
    ],
    [
      'Jack Moores loc', '37.9908372',
      '23.7383394', '2',
      'id-67'
    ]
  ];

  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'),
    mapOptions);

  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  markers = [];

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var place = locations[i][0];
    var placeLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      title: place,
      position: placeLoc,
      icon: pinImage(i + 1)

    });

    markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
    map.setZoom(10);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
  });
  hideMap();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mymap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map1" onClick="showMap()">Show</div>
<div id="map2" onClick="hideMap()">Hide</div>
<div id="mymap" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```